# Checkbox angularjs 1.6 material checked by default

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use the material angular checkbox, and set it by default as checked, but it is displayed non-checked, what is wrong?

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="loan.currentAsPermanent" aria-label="Checkbox 1" [checked]="isChecked" aria-checked="true"/> Permanent address same as current address </md-checkbox>
```

Comment: Show your code pls.

Comment: <md-checkbox ng-model="loan.currentAsPermanent" aria-label="Checkbox 1" />Permanent address same as current address                                        </md-checkbox>
 i need to checkbox is checked and hide this div  by default
<div class="permanent-address" ng-hide="loan.currentAsPermanent">

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-model instead as per docs

```
<md-checkbox aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-model="isChecked" aria-checked="true"/> Permanent address same as current address </md-checkbox>
```

Ref. from [official Docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Change `[checked]="isChecked"` by `ng-model="isChecked"`

Or keep `ng-model="loan.currentAsPermanent"` and check if `loan.currentAsPermanent` is true

Answer (score 0):

`<md-checkbox ng-model="loan.currentAsPermanent" aria-label="Checkbox 1">
Permanent address same as current address</md-checkbox>`
add this code in controller
`$scope.loan = {};
 $scope.loan.currentAsPermanent = true;`